# What is the correct way to apply the yii2 cache?

Tags: php, caching, yii2, yii-components, yii2-basic-app

As I'm new to the cache mechanism, I gone through the yii2 [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html). As per the documentation, I added the below config in db.php in yii2 basic application.

```
<?php

return [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_new',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root123',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'enableQueryCache' => true,
  'queryCacheDuration' => 86400,
  'enableSchemaCache' => true,
  // Name of the cache component used to store schema information
  'schemaCache' => 'cache',
  // Duration of schema cache.
  'schemaCacheDuration' => 86400, // 24H it is in seconds

];
```

also I added the cache component in web.php

```
'components' => [
   'cache' => [
      'class' => 'yii\caching\ApcCache'
   ]
]
```

And added the below code while retrieving a record from clients table.

```
$db = Clients::getDb();
$client = $db->cache(function ($db)use($id) {
  return Clients::find()->where(['id' => $id])->all();
});
```

I assume my client table one record ex)$id = 3 is cached. So next time if I try to retrieve same record from clients table it will pull from cache not from scratch.

My questions are

1. What I did above is this correct or anything I need to configure
   more?
2. Where it is storing in the local system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you install Apc cache in your server?

Comment: Looks correct. Do you have any problems with it? Don't forget about cache invalidation in cases when cached data may be changed... http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#cache-dependencies

Comment: @ThanhPV No, I'm not installed anything related to cache.

Comment: @MaximKorshunov You mean when any changes happen in db, we need to update/flush the cache and rebuild again?

Comment: @ManikandanS yes, I mean flushing. That's common practice.

Comment: @ManikandanS If you don't install APC cache, or APCu for php7, you should define cache component to use FileCache or DbCache :)

Comment: @MaximKorshunov ok thank you. I will flush as soon as db record updated.

Answer (score 0):

what you did is correct for query caching, found in [data caching here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html).

there are more caching mechanisms available, like [fragment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-fragment.html), [page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-page.html) or [http caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-http.html)

as far as i know, the place where the cached data is stored depends on the caching component. [apc stores in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678676/where-does-apc-store-the-data)

yii's FileCache will store files under /runtime

good to know you can flush caches with yii's console command `yii cache/flush-all`

Comment: Thanks for your info. I will try and let you know